# Private Blockchain ETH Price Display in Parity

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

I have fired up what I think is a private blockchain in parity.  But I still see "Updated conversion rate to Ξ1 = US$88.11" and that is the correct price as of now.

So I'm wondering if this means that my parity is still readinh from homestead, and not the private blockchain?

How can I verify I'm running parity on the private chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it defaults to the foundation ETH chain token value. It does not make any sense for a develop chain except for having realisitc USD value attached to your devETH to calculate transaction costs (see `--usd-per-tx` which adjusts the minimum gas price).

If this is an annoyance, you can reset it with `--usd-per-eth 0.0001` or any value you like.

Comment: Okay but let's say I'm using parity to connect to ETC?  What is changed there?  What is it reading in that case so that you're seeing a real-time ETC value, not ETH?

Comment: You can pass an API to `--usd-per-eth` which points to the ETC price instead of the ETH price.

Comment: What I want is for it to read from the current local blockchain.  I'm running a custom chain spec file, and having the ETH price (or ETC) is confusing.  I would prefer nothing.

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/4123), feel free to follow it and join the discussion.

Comment: The issue you linked is about currency symbols, not the exchange rate API.